# How to convert torch int64 to torch LongTensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am going through a course which uses a deprecated version of PyTorch which does not change `torch.int64` to `torch.LongTensor` as needed. The current section of code which is throwing the error is:

`loss = loss_fn(Ypred, Ytrain_) # calc loss on the prediction`

I believe the dtype should be changed in thhis section though:

`Ytrain_ = torch.from_numpy(y_train.values).view(1, -1)[0]`.

When testing the data-type by using `Ytrain_.dtype` it returns `torch.int64`. I have tried to convert it by applying the `long()` function as such: `Ytrain_ = Ytrain_.long()` to no avail.

I have also tried looking for it in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html#tensor-attributes-doc) but it seems that it says `torch.int64` OR `torch.long` which I assume means `torch.int64` should work.

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 9     loss = loss_fn(Ypred, Ytrain_) # calc loss on the prediction
RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Int for argument #2 'target'
```

Comment: do not convert, just set the type you want while creating a tensor

Comment: I have tried `Ytrain_ = torch.from_numpy(y_train.values).view(1, -1)[0].long()` to set it as well but this did not work. This is only my second course for PyTorch so maybe I am missing it. Maybe you can give an example..

Comment: ahh , torch.LongTensor is tensor type not dtype try to  not convert at all, and btw while nn processing you should have floats

Comment: Very good! I had not realized there was a difference between the `dtype` and `type`.

Answer (score 9):

As stated by `user8426627` you want to change the tensor type, not the data type. Therefore the solution was to add `.type(torch.LongTensor)` to convert it to a `LongTensor`.

Final code:

`Ytrain_ = torch.from_numpy(Y_train.values).view(1, -1)[0].type(torch.LongTensor)`

Test tensor type:

`Ytrain_.type()`

`'torch.LongTensor'`